# Create comment with rectangle anchor

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API V3 to create anchored comments on Image.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/create

Using their API explorer I tried different values for anchor

```
"anchor": "{'r': 'head', 'a': [{'rect': {'x': 100, 'y': 150, 'w': 20, 'h': 20}}]}"
```

I expect it to create comment with 20X20 rectangle anchor on Image, but it doesn't.

Did anyone tried this API, maybe had similar problems? I could not find any examples or related question anywhere.

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  please edit your question and include your code enough that we can test and describe the issue you are having with your code.

Comment: Hello! This appears to be a bug. I have reported it to the Google's Public Issue Tracker. For any updates regarding this you can visit the following link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146053105 Cheers!

Comment: @DaImTo As I was not writing any code and just testing it through their API explorer, there was no code to include.

Comment: @carlesgg97 Thank you, I been struggling with it for a while. I hope they will fix it soon